# Opening several files with python threading

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-3.7

I have several files I want to open at the same time and pull data from and write them each to their own files. I'm currently doing something like this:

```py
files = os.listdir(FilePath)
for file in files:
    with open(os.path.join(FilePath, file), 'r') as LFILE:
        LFILE.read()
```

Will I need to some how read all the files, put the file in a list and then have each thread read down the list and remove the file once its been read? Or is there a better way to open files and not read the same one more then once?

Comment: No, just define a function that reads a file and using `threading.Pool` map file names to this function. Take a look at the very first example: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the reputation to ask for further clarification in a comment, but if you're not aggregating the data in such a way that info needs to be shared across files, I would just map the list of files to a pool, like so:

```
def analyze_file(filename: str):
    with open(filename, 'r') as LFILE:
        # analyze the file how you'd like
        # store results in a string
        with open(filename + 'analyzed.txt', 'w') as result_fh:
            result_fh.write(results)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with multiprocessing.Pool(4) as p:
        p.map(
                 analyze_file,
                 [os.path.join(FilePath, file) for file in os.listdir(FilePath)]
             )
```